# When should I use git add, before or after making changes to the file?

Tags: git

Spend a few hours googling and in every article authors use 'git add' before and after making changes to the files, makes me a bit confused.

Comment: You can do either. `git add` simply adds files to be tracked by git.

Comment: Specific examples would help. Absent context, it’s hard to say exactly why the authors did what they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you should use it just before `git commit`.

You *can* use it at different times, you just need to know what it does:

- Git stores *commits*, not files.  (But commits themselves store files, so that's fine.)
- Everything inside a commit is read-only, frozen for all time.  It all lives forever, or at least, as long as the commit itself lives.  But none of it can ever be changed.  The files that are inside a commit are in a special Git-only format: only Git can actually *use* these files.
- This means you literally cannot work on the *committed* files.  You have to work on a copy.  Git extracts the committed files for you, into a work area.  This is your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  All the files that you can see and edit are these work-tree copies.  They are not in the repository!  They are only in your work-area, for you to do whatever you want.
- If you make new files, or delete existing files, in your work-tree, nothing happens to Git's copies.
- Git keeps an invisible *third* copy of each file.  (Technically this isn't really a copy—it's much fancier—but it works OK to think of it this way.)  This third copy is in the special *format* that Git uses inside commits, but unlike the copy of the file in the commit, you can *replace* it.

What `git add` does is manipulate this third copy.  Think of the third copy as being *between* the current commit (frozen, can't change) and the work-tree version (normal file, you can see it and edit it).  The extra in-between copy is in what Git calls its *index* or its *staging area*.  (These are two names for the same thing.)

What `git add` does is take the work-tree copy and make the index copy match.  In effect, it copies the work-tree copy over top of the index copy.  Git calls this *staging* the file for commit.  The file was already there—already in the staging area—it's just that it was the old version, not the one you've edited.

When you `git add` a totally new file, the totally new file gets compressed into the special frozen format and put in the staging area.  There's no copy in any commit yet, but now you have two copies (vs the three you'd have if there were a committed copy).

Until you run `git commit`, this *staged* copy is just sitting there in Git's index / staging-area.  When you do run `git commit`, Git takes every file that is in the staging area, in the form it has in there *right then*, and packages those files up into a new commit.  Since they're already in the frozen *format*, this is particularly fast and easy.

#### Remember, if you edit a file, you probably want to add it again

If you edit a file and use `git add`, you've replaced the staged copy with a new staged copy based on what you have in your work-tree.  If you edit the work-tree file *again*, you now have three different copies:

- one in the current commit, which is frozen;
- a different one from your earlier `git add`; and
- the one you modified now in your work-tree.

If you `git commit` now without using `git add`, the committed copy will match the staged / index copy.  That's not usually what you want—though sometimes it *is* what you want; you can use the fact that there are *three* versions to good effect, sometimes.

#### Remember that `git checkout` writes both the index and your work-tree

Note that each `git checkout` that picks some new commit to view or work on/with has to fill in your work-tree so that you can see and work on the files.  But to be ready for the *next* commit, it also has to overwrite the index copies of each file.  Things in Git's index aren't committed, and things in your work-tree aren't even in the repository, so neither one is safely frozen for all time.

To make sure something really is safely saved away, make a commit!  You can make temporary commits on temporary branches, and shuffle them around, and eventually throw out the temporary commits.  (They're frozen, and a little bit hard to get rid of completely, but it's usually better to have extra commits that you don't need, than not to have made a commit that you end up needing.)

Answer (score 3):

`git add` adds the specific content currently in that file. What you do after a `git add` stays in the work tree, but when you commit, the content that gets committed is what you added.

Answer (score 3):

`git add` does two things: it stages untracked files, and it stages changes to tracked files. Using `git add` on an unchanged, tracked file wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

git commits your index, not the currently working directory.
If you changed several files and want to commit only one of them, you can git add  and than commit, and only files "added" to index will be committed.

Learn what is working directory, what is index, what is stash, what is repository and remote repository.